# Idle Model 4B running > 115 C = damaged?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, temperature

So today I noticed a 4B I was bringing up on Ubuntu 20.04 (server) was actually crashing due to heat.

- I managed to stop docker etc, and captured CPU measurements of ~115 C.
- I was purchased late last year, so I don't know which firmware it has - how to upgrade with ubuntu?
- I've ordered fans and heatsink - as I do have plans for doing more than idling..
- I'm using a 3A goobay PSU, although it may really be a charger which I hear could cause issues?
- It seems its getting way more hot than what I find online, so I'm wondering if it is damaged somehow?
- It runs until it gets too hot, but why isn't the throttling stopping the temperature hike?

Comment: If you don't get undervoltage the PSU should be OK. I suppose your Pi wasn't idling: did "bringing up" the server involve software installation, starting new services and the like? 115 degrees is pretty extreme, but in general the Pi 4 is quite useless without at least a heatsink.

Comment: I don't think the PSU has under voltage, and I did try a USBC dock which should provide ok quality voltage with same results. I didn't actually install much, as I just started it using an SD card from an RPi3 I had. Initially that worked ok without the overheating, but then it started overheating after ~50 hours of operation?

Comment: Who knows what happened after 50 hours... Point is, any temperature above 80 C is too high, and you generally need cooling with a Pi 4. It is a bit alarming that the throttling didn't prevent the CPU from getting that hot, I would test a different Pi4 board if I had the chance.

Comment: Looks a bit like the CPU throttling is somehow switched off in a driver or the firmware. The CPU should absolutely prevent getting that high by itself

Comment: Even with throttling off, how should it ever get to 115 C when idling? I've sent it for RMA, so hopefully they'll recognise that this is not normal behaviour.. I think it somehow got so hot that got broken, and now consistently builds up heat :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up RMAing it.. new one works so.. possibly a defective cpu..